# Magento CE 1.9 - Credit Memo is wrong in email but fine in PDF

Tags: email, pdf, magento-1.9.1

We have an weird error with an magento store. When we create an credit memo from backend and tick to email the customer, the email customer receives (and also on front view when we login using the customer credentials) the credit memo shows wrong information - no refund adjustments, no. of products everything, total price etc.

Weird issue is that after the credit memo is create, if we click Export and the PDF is being generated, all the information from the PDF match the credit memo but again, the email the customer receives and the credit memo showed on the front view (from client panel) shows a credit memo with wrong information. Wrong information means this: a full refund, not a partial one (example:we refund just 2 out of 3 products and we also modify the shipping price).

Does anyone had a similar issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what the issue was - I had an 3rd party module that was rewriting the totals of the order - the total that was used in the order details page and also when the email was sent BUT for the PDF generator, a different method was used, and that's why the PDF total was showing the right information -

So in the future, if you have this issue just try and read all the modules you have and see in the xml def. of each module, if the order_totals (as i recall) is being overwrited.

Have a good day.